# Swift UIImage won't work with Umlauts

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, diacritics

I´m trying to load load Images using following code:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: name)
```

This code works fine with all files, but returns `nil` if there is an umlaut in the filename.

I found this thread, saying UIImage should be able to handle umlauts but my testing tells me its not.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44646

All the files are in included in the project. If I rename them everything works just fine.

**Edit:** all images are .png files.

Comment: You're going to have to post a lot more code for us to go on. I'll try to test what you're saying but this little amount of code and context makes it difficult to match your environment.

Comment: Are your image files in an Asset catalog?

Comment: As far as I tested again, `UIImage.init(named:)` fails to handle image names including Umlauts in some cases. Try `imageView.image = UIImage(named: name.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping)`.

Comment: I just did a quick test, and it worked fine for me... Original file names: `YourCät.png` and `MyCät.png`. Added `MyCät.png` to default Assets catalog, added `YourCät.png` as a file in the project. `theImageView.image = UIImage(named: "YourCät")` and `theImageView.image = UIImage(named: "MyCät")` and `theImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "MyCät")` all work without problem.

Comment: @ColGraff there´s not much more to it. I get the image name as a string, I check if it exists, if so set it, if not set a default image.

`if UIImage(named: name) != nil{ 
spotImageView.image = UIImage(named: name+".png")
}else{
spotImageView.image = UIImage(named: "platzhalter_00")
}`

Comment: @OOPer 'name.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping' - same issue.

Comment: @DonMag yes, all image files are inside the same Asset catalog assigned to the target.

Comment: @ChrisTheGreat, then your issue is another thing which I can observe in my old project. You need to provide more info to show what is specific in your case.

Comment: I don´t know, what else could be relevant to it.
If I hardcode `UIImage(named: "Küche")` it returns `nil`.
If I rename the asset to "Kueche" however and call `UIImage(named: "Kueche")` everything works fine.

Comment: Did some more testing, `name.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping)` seems so work now. Thank you @OOPer

Comment: @ChrisTheGreat, happy to hear that. IMO, file/resource name matching should work for non-canonical inputs. Better send a [bug report to Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).